# Hibernate created an automatic breaking constraint

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

So I have 3 classes, `Category`, `Question` and `Comment`.
Both classes have a `OneToMany` relationship to `Comment`.

For some reason Hibernate has decided to put in a constraint on `Comment` resulting in the following exception:

```
ERROR: insert or update on table "comment" violates foreign key constraint "fknapu44p12w4v7wreaog7vgc80"
Detail: Key (q_comment)=(03f7ed17-4fa1-48d9-ac17-9842e233fde4) is not present in table "category".
```

Both `Question` and `Category` have to following bit of code:

```
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = {CascadeType.ALL})
@JoinColumn(name = "t_comment")
@LazyCollection(LazyCollectionOption.FALSE)
private List<Comment> comment;
```

And it seems as if I can correctly save the `Category` object with a new `Comment` in the list, but it breaks when I do the same to `Question`

So does anyone have any idea of what might cause this?

To clarify: the tables where created by hibernate which generated the following sql:

```
create table category (id varchar(255) not null, color varchar(7), name varchar(255), parent_questionnaire varchar(255), primary key (id))
create table comment (id varchar(255) not null, comment varchar(2048), timestamp int8, sent_by varchar(255), session varchar(255), t_recommendation varchar(255), t_comment varchar(255), primary key (id))
create table question (id varchar(255) not null, question varchar(255), type int4, parent_category varchar(255), primary key (id))
alter table if exists comment add constraint FKnapu44p12w4v7wreaog7vgc80 foreign key (t_comment) references category
```

Comment: As it sais, it violates a foreign key constraint. So I am assuming you added a foreign key constraint on that table. Could you provide the sql code that was used to create those tables

Comment: Yeah, of course. Problem is that it was created by hibernate itself. but give me a second and I'll pull out the sql it used

Comment: Were you able to solve this?

Comment: yeah, it kind of makes sense when you think about it. using a one to many it must create a constraint from `comment` to the others as it is the one holding the join column. And it ofcourse breaks as you can only have a constraint against one table. But changing it to a `ManyToMany` relation solves the issue